# Can all theorems be deduced directly from the ZFC axioms?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I stumbled upon a website called [metamath](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmset.html) that claims that all theorems can be deduced directly from the ZFC axioms. Here is the exact claim:

> Essentially everything that is possible to know in mathematics can be
>   derived from a handful of axioms known as Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory,
>   which is the culmination of many years of effort to isolate the
>   essential nature of mathematics and is one of the most profound
>   achievements of mankind.

Is it really possible to be able to do this?

Comment: You can try reading the proofs in the website ...

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. A theorem is only a theorem of some theory. ZFC trivially proves exactly its own theorems.

Comment: I agree with Malice Vidrine, the only answer to this question can be "the theorems founded on ZFC can be deduced from ZFC", but that hurts to say.

Comment: This is a valid question, although the OP could have made the reference a bit more precise (see my answer).

Comment: Just a pun: a system that allows to derive everything is inconsistent ... I hope ZFC is not.

Comment: @RobArthan "This is a valid question". I disagree because it is not clear whether the known theorems are meant or all possible theorems. If "theorem" simply means "a true statement", then ZFC cannot prove all theorems. The question is only valid after "theorem" has been clarified.

Comment: @Peter: the OP's link contains the strong claim that I quoted in my answer and which the OP has summarised in the title of the question. It is perfectly valid to ask whether that claim is justified. It would have been better if the question had been self-contained rather than requiring one to follow the link, but nonetheless all the information needed to provide a meaningful answer is there.

Comment: @RobArthan Exactly, the question is not self-contained. And it is part of the spirit of this site that a question should be independent of links.

Comment: @Peter I have now added the claim. Would you now agree that the question is self-contained?

Comment: @AidanRocke Yes, now the question is OK. I vote for reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metamath website does contain the somewhat brash claim:

> *Essentially everything that is possible to know in mathematics can be derived from a handful of axioms known as Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, which is the culmination of many years of effort to isolate the essential nature of mathematics and is one of the most profound achievements of mankind.*

I think it is true to say that the vast majority of mathematics can at least in principle be formalised in ZF set theory, but there are certainly things that cannot be proved in ZF, e.g., the consistency of ZF. Stronger systems than ZF have been proposed and are used, e.g., set theory with Grothendieck universes as advocated in Cohn's *Universal Algebra*, and Mostowski-Kelley-Morse set theory, which is well-known via from the presentation in Kelley's *General Topology*. Both these systems are strong enough to prove the consistency of ZF.

Tools like metamath make it possible to carry out formalisations in practice and not just in principle, but they don't provide a way round the incompleteness theorems.

Comment: Another point I just read on their website is Godel's first incompleteness theorem which says that 'no finite set of axioms or axiom schemes can completely describe any consistent theory strong enough to include arithmetic.'

Doesn't this mean that there are some theorems that can't be deduced from the ZFC axioms?

Comment: "I think it is true to say that the vast majority of mathematics can at least in principle be formalised in ZF set theory..."

No way.  Enough mathematics uses infix expressions which are impossible to formalize in what we now call ZF, since those expressions have formation rules for terms which renders expressions like a + b + c meaningless in ZF.  And no, you can't formalize a + b + c as ((a + b) + c), because it doesn't say that.  And no a + b + c does not mean ((a + b) + c) or/and (a + (b + c)), since if it did it would qualify as a disjunction or a conjunction.  But, it's an addition.

Comment: @AidanRocke: Yes. The consistency of ZFC is a theorem that cannot be derived from the ZFC axioms. (Strictly speaking "finite set of axioms or axiom schemes" should read "recursively enumerable set of axioms".)

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: the standard reading of $a + b + c$ as a shorthand for $(a + b) + c$ is utterly harmless. If $+$ is associative it is also harmless to read $a + b + c$ as $a + (b + c)$. This kind of issue is of considerable practical importance in formalising mathematics, but not very significant from a theoretical point of view. Your "No way" is not justified.

Comment: It isn't harmless to read a + b + c as a shorthand for (a + b) + c, and also at the same time harmless to read a + b + c as a + (b + c).  A proof of ((a + b) + c) = ((b + a) + c) just involves replacing one expression by another according to the commutative law of addition.  On the other hand, a proof of ((a + b) + c) = (b + (a + c)) involves *both* a commutation *and* an association.  What you claim as utterly harmless completely confuses these two sorts of proofs.  And theoretically speaking commutation and association are different.

Comment: This is not about proof: proof happens after you have resolved these matters of surface syntax. I.e., given $a + b + c$, the agreed conventions for putting the brackets in should be applied before thinking about formal proof. You are conflating parsing with proof.

Comment: @AidanRocke - about Godel : NOT exactly. *Theorem* of ZFC means "formally derivable from ZFC axioms by rules of inference". Thus, G's result must be read (roughly) : "there are true *facts* about e.g. arithmetic that are not (formally) derivable from the axioms".

Comment: The question here was "Can all theorems *be deduced* [emphasis added] directly from the ZFC axioms?"

Now Rob Arthan is telling me that this question wasn't about proof.  That doesn't make any sense at all.  Whether something or not can be deduced is a matter of proof.

Also, Rob, if you don't mind me calling you such, do you think that with respect to addition on the natural numbers that (a + b + c) = (b + a + c) is true, false, or meaningless?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: the informal equation $(a + b  + c) = (b + a + c)$ becomes is true in a commutative groupregardless of how I choose to put enough brackets in to make it a formal predicate in the first-order language of a group (using additive notation for the binary function symbol $+$).

Comment: Alright, so it seems that you agree that (a + b + c) = (b + a + c) is true.  But, you can't prove it formally, and neither can I, nor can anyone else.

Comment: No, that is not what my comment says.I am saying that one needs to agrere how to map the informal equation into a predicate in a formal system before it becomes amenable to formal proof.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA When you say 'facts' does that include theorems? If so, that's identical to what I said.

Comment: @AidanRocke - "facts" include *theorems*; but according to the so-called "platonic" view, the mathematical truth "are there", irrespective of the fact that we have a proof of it or not. Following the incompleteness theorems, there are "true" sentences of arithmetic that are unprovable, i.e. formally underivable from the axioms. So, in this sense they are not theorems of formal arithmetic.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Do you actually claim that $(a+b+c)=(b+a+c)$ is not provable in ZF ? Even PA can prove this statement.

Comment: @Peter ZF here refers to the formal theory of the Metamath site (see the original question).  I don't think that (a + b + c), nor (b + a + c) can get formulated with what the Metamath site allows.  Note, (a + b + c) is neither ((a + b) + c) nor (a + (b + c)).  Note also that Rob Arthan agreed that (a + b + c) = (b + a + c) is not formal, but instead informal.  So, (a + b +c) = (b + a + c) is not even a statement.  Therefore, (a + b + c) = (b + a + c) cannot get proved where 'proof' refers to a formalized sequence following what the Metamath site requires.

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood: I think your objection has little merit. It is undoubtedly true that the vast majority of mathematical theorems - essentially all of them, to be a little polemical - can be formalized within ZFC.  If $+$ is a binary operation, then $a + b + c$ is not a well formed expression, but is just an informal shorthand for an actual expression such as $(a+b)+c$ or $a + (b+c)$ according to the preference of the author.  The commutativity and associativity of addition of natural numbers are indeed provable in ZFC and in much weaker theories.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I've never understood this objection. The statement "One plus one equals two" also isn't a statement in the language of arithmetic, but it has a non-controversial encoding by a statement in the language of arithmetic. Harping on this sort of issue is just bizarre, in my opinion, in the absence of a truly hard-to-faithfully-represent informal statement. If you truly want to be that pedantic about things, the right version of the OP's question is: "Does every informal statement considered a theorem in mathematics have a corresponding statement in the language of set theory (contd)

Comment: which $(i)$ would uncontroversially be agreed to be a "translation" of the original statement into the language of set theory and $(ii)$ is a theorem of ZFC?" But I don't see the value in splitting hairs this finely at the moment; it's clear what the OP asked, and - while this concern could be relevant to a different question about foundations (and raises interesting issues of its own, like how we analyze $(i)$) - I don't think this adds anything of value.

Comment: @CarlMummert "If + is a binary operation, then a+b+c is not a well formed expression, but is just an informal shorthand for an actual expression such as (a+b)+c or a+(b+c)"  Neither (a+b)+c nor a+(b+c) is an actual expression that can appear in a formal system.  Not according to a more usual definition where terms an m-expression style.  Nor according to the metamath site.

Comment: @CarlMummert "It is undoubtedly true that the vast majority of mathematical theorems - essentially all of them, to be a little polemical - can be formalized within ZFC." I had an answer to the original question which said "no", but it got deleted by voting of three other people than myself.  But, my answer relies on the concept of a theorem as a formally provable statement.  In other words, a theorem consists of a well-formed expression derived purely by permissible rules of inference... continued

Comment: @CarlMummert I don't recognize any definition of a "mathematical theorem", and hesitate at such as more than a personal concept.  Some have said that a mathematical theorem is anything that people find convincing.  But, I don't agree that all people find the same things convincing (e. g. some will feel convinced that (a + b) + c was an actual expression, I won't feel convinced).  So, I don't agree that everyone has the same concept of a mathematical theorem.  Thus, one might reject your claim on the basis that "mathematical theorem" is ambiguous at best.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood The crucial point is whether a statement can be proven in ZFC. How the formula is written is not important because every expression can easily be translated in the ZFC-formalism. The claim that $a+b=b+a$ (easily implying $(a+b)+c=(b+a)+c$) cannot be formally proven in ZFC is just wrong.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I agree with you concerning that "theorem" has to be specified, but I think the edited question is specific enough. I voted to reopen and turned my downvote in an upvote.

Comment: @Peter "The claim that a+b=b+a..." a+b = b+a is not a "claim" in the sense of being a well-formed formula according to the metamath site (and I wouldn't use a definition that makes it well-formed).  If 'a' is a number, and 'b' is a number, then the closure law for addition yields that (a + b) is a number, but doesn't yield that a + b is a number: http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/addcl.html  Also, if both '+' and '=' are functions, a + b = b + a could mean (((a + b) = b) + a) or (a + ((b = b) + a)).  Anyways, if you still disagree, I'll need an argument that a + b and (a + b) + c are well-formed.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood The difference between "$a+b$" and "$(a+b)$" is harmless. The value of $(a+b)$ is the value of the sum $a+b$. So, if you claim that $a+b$ and $(a+b)+c$ are not well-formed, you must given an argument for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83080/discussion-between-peter-and-doug-spoonwood).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Want to join in our chat ?